# Compound contiguous links to lines in a network and find isolated lines

Tags: postgis, postgresql, union, crossing

I want to compound the red and green links (lines between the poinst) to one or more lines. I need it to finde the green links that not touching the red lines in my network.

Step 1: compound touching links to lines
Step 2: find the lines don't touching, crossing the network

How does it works with postgresql ?

[image]

Comment: What is the criteria for determining "isolated lines"?   Sets of connected links containing no nodes of degree > 2?

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to cluster your lines by intersection - use `ST_ClusterDBSCAN` with `eps := 0`:

```
SELECT *,
       ST_ClusterDBSCAN(<geom>, 0, 1) OVER() AS _clst
FROM   <lines>
;
```

to assign a cluster id (`_clst`) to connected segments on a per-row basis.

---

From here you could `ST_Union/ST_Collect` based on `_clst`:

```
SELECT ST_Union(<geom>) AS geom
FROM   (
  SELECT *,
         ST_ClusterDBSCAN(<geom>, 0, 1) OVER() AS _clst
  FROM   <lines>
) q
GROUP BY
       _clst
;
```

or, in order to find only those disconnected sub-networks, make a selection by `ST_Length`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT ST_Union(<geom>) AS geom
  FROM   (
    SELECT *,
             ST_ClusterDBSCAN(<geom>, 0, 1) OVER() AS _clst
    FROM   <lines>
  ) q
  GROUP BY
         _clst
) q
ORDER BY
       ST_Length(geom) DESC
OFFSET 1
;
```

Comment: `ST_Union` doesn't merge adjacent lines.   `ST_LineMerge` might be more effective here.  But that depends on whether ordering by length meets the requirement to identify disconnected lines.  (If it does, then the union is probably superfluous?)

Comment: @dr_jts we're only interested in total cluster length (thus `ST_Union`) in those examples, I don't see any incentive for more sophisticated topological editing. Not sure what OP is really after, but the gist of my answer is the clustering which leaves you with plenty options.

Comment: Understood.   In that case using `ST_Collect` will be much faster than `ST_Union`.

Comment: thx, st_union was works for my case. i try with st_collect to test the perfromance. Is it possible to combine the clustering with additional attribute ? maybe the attribute is quality and have three values 1, 2, 3. group by _clst and quality -

Comment: @Tibor `ST_Collect` is a lot faster, it merely *collects* geometries into a (minimally fitting) super-type; `ST_Union` however dissolves and collapses overlapping geometries first - costly but useful for 'dirty' networks. The actual benefit of `ST_ClusterDBSCAN` being a Window function is that is assigns a numeric id (`_clst` here) to each row of the input set. So in effect, you can treat the result set like the initial table, but with that additional attribute. You can group by it plus all columns that you have available. Is that what you mean?

Comment: And it should be possible to use `SUM(ST_Length(..))` and avoid collecting the geometries entirely.  SUM can be used as a aggregate function with `GROUP BY _clst` or as a window function `OVER (PARTITION BY _clst)`

Comment: ST_Collect To ST_Union is 1:3 - by over 3 million links collect 10 sec und union 30 sec. both okay. Grouping can't try.