# How to get all polygons that are spatially interconnected with each other in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, intersection, clustering

I have the following scenario:

```
SELECT * FROM owner_poly;
>
|id| owner_id | polygon_ids |
|1 |    10    |'{1,2,3,20}' |
|2 |    10    |'{12,22,2}'  |
|3 |    10    |'{1}'        |
|4 |    10    |'{12}'       |
|5 |    11    |'{5,7}'      |
|6 |    11    |'{5,9}'      |
|7 |    12    |'{15,77}'    |
|8 |    12    |'{19,47}'    |

SELECT * FROM poly;
>
|    id    |       geom      |
|    1     |MultiPolygon(..) |
|    2     |MultiPolygon(..) |
....
```

I have a `owner_poly` table that stores an `owner_id` and associated polygons through their id's as an array. It is ensured that all polygons inside one array are interconnected. Now I need to group them by their interconnectivity with other arrays. For the above example I need the following output:

```
| owner_id | polygon_ids      |
|    10    |'{1,2,3,12,20,22}'|
|    11    |'{5,7,9}'         |
|    12    |'{15,77}'         |
|    12    |'{19,47}'         |
```

All polygons for owner_id `10` and `11` were interconnected and, thus, need to be stored in one array. For `12` it is not the case and, thus, they stay as they are.

Now I am trying to wrap my head around to group them based on the array values but couldn't find a solution.

Therefore I am wondering if a PostGIS function / algorithm exists that could identify interconnected geometries. For instance: id `4` is connected with id `1` through id `2` (polygon_id `12->2`), but may not directly intersect with it spatially.

Could someone provide me with a guideline for either way (through the array or the geometry)?

Comment: I am just providing theory. You can try to use dissolve(ST_UNION) operation group by owner_id if you know polygons are adjacent for each owner_id. If you are not sure which polygons are not adjacent irrespective of owner_id, then dissolve all the polygons in the layer and convert multipolygon to polygons and then apply contains relation to reassign ids from original table.

Comment: st_clusterdbscan

Comment: have a look at this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408695/compound-contiguous-links-to-lines-in-a-network-and-find-isolated-lines) which uses st_clusterdbscan to union connected lines

Comment: @JoeBe happy to give this a shot if you can provide a sql file with dummy data via a github gist or so